# Efficiently querying for many to many to find X is not related to Y

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a many to many pivot table for comments, eg:

`user_id | post_id | comment
234     | 123     | "This project is awesome"
235     | 123     | "This is so cool!"
234     | 124     | "I really like the look of this one"
235     | 124     | "What are you going to make next?"
235     | 125     | "So cool to finally see this!"`

I need to write a query to select * from users who have not commented on specific post(s). The best method I can think of is a query with a subselect, like so:

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM comments WHERE post_id IN (123,125))`

This feels inefficient (largely due to the subselect) and I am trying to find a better query to perform this operation. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

You could replace pivot with your pivot table:

```
select u.* from users u left join pivot p on u.id = p.user_id
group by u.id` having count(case when p.post_id in (123,125) then 1 else 0 end) =0
```

Comment: replace pivot with your pivot table

Comment: This was my first idea, but it won't work because it is a many to many. Since the users has a comment on post 124, they will appear in this list, even though they have commented on 123/125